# MVC core 5.0 update js via Viewmodel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

im trying to update data in javascript via viewmodel.
When the side loads it works.

```
     window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        let listModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
        LoadAllInfoSpots(listModel);
    
    });
```

But when i call my js function

```
function afterClickOnFlorplan() {
        setTimeout(function () {
           let listModel =@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
        LoadAllInfoSpots(listModel);
        }, 1500);

    }
```

the `let listmodel` is the same as when i loaded the side. with a count of 4.

i know the viewmodel is updating.
[image: pic of the viewmodel updatede]

but as you can see `let listmodel`  is not updated in my js code.

[image: old listmodel]

So why is the `let listmodel` the same all the time?

hope you can help me.

Model:

```
 public class SelectorModel
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string Cords { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class SelectorViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectorModel> SelectorModels { get; set; }

    }
```

the first IActionResult:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            LoadInfoSpotsFromDB load = new LoadInfoSpotsFromDB();
            string first = load.LoadFirstImage();
            SetFirstIMageCookie(first);
            List<SelectorModel> loaede = load.Load(first);
            selectorViewModel = new SelectorViewModel
            {
                SelectorModels = loaede
            };           

            return View(selectorViewModel);
        }
```

the `IActionResult` that update the ViewModel

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index([FromBody] string dontremove)
        {
            selectorViewModel = null;
            LoadInfoSpotsFromDB load = new LoadInfoSpotsFromDB();            

            List<SelectorModel> loaede = load.Load(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["ImageName"]);            

            selectorViewModel = new SelectorViewModel
            {
                SelectorModels = loaede
            };


            return View(selectorViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: I could see that in your `afterClickOnFlorplan()` function you are using the setTimeout for 1500 milliseconds. I am assuming that maybe your function is taking some time to fetch the data. It could be possible that 1500 milliseconds is not enough and it is taking more time and due to that reason you are getting the `Count=1`. You could try to increase the setTimeout value and see whether it makes any difference. Test with different values, it could help you understand the approximate time to load the data successfully.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT. Thanks for your response. I just tried to set the timeout to 10000 milliseconds, but my ```listmodel``` is still 4. And i want to get a count of 1